# is it possible to ignore .gitignore rules in subdirectory?

Tags: git

I want to ignore all of .gitignore rules in subdirectory except .gitignore rules in root.

for example:
I already have `.gitignore` file in a directory structure `/a`.

And also have `.gitignore` file in `/a/b`. Assume `/a` has `a.txt` and `b.txt` files.

`/a/b` has `.config` file. `.gitignore` defines `.config` in `/a/b`.

`.config` file will be ignored by `.gitignore` in `/a/b`.

But I really want to track `.config` file by ignoring rules of `.gitignore` in subdirectory.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Your question isn't too clear, but if there are some subdirectories where you want different gitignore rules, you can just create a new .gitignore in that directory.

Say you have:

```
project/.gitignore
project/stuff/.gitignore
```

The .gitignore in stuff/ will override the .gitignore in the root directory.

`git help gitignore` or `man gitignore` has quite a bit more information about what's possible.

Comment: I think the OP is asking if you have a directory structure `/a/b/c` and you update `.gitignore` in `/a/b`, is it possible in `/a/b/c` to ignore the rules in `/a/b` and instead only use rules from `/a`.

Comment: Yeah, if that was the question, it is possible to negate rules in a .gitignore further down the chain. `"An optional prefix !  which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again."`

Comment: @signine Doesn't work with directories. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36108231/624787).

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that: the `inner .gitignore` will merge with `outer .gitignore` with higher priority, not simply override.

Comment: @eric wang apparently a subdirectory does not merge,  but overrides: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: "the .gitignore in stuff/ will override the .gitignore in the root directory.". Too vague. I added an empty `.gitignore` file in a subdir but the root rules still apply under it. @Nick Zalutskiy answer worked.

Answer (score 60):

Lets say you want to include `node_modules` in your repository, but some module down the line has `.gitignore` of its own. You can negate the rules by adding the following to your root `.gitignore` file:

```
# Make sure to include everything in node_modules.
!node_modules/**
```

Comment: Is there a more generic way to do this? lets say I've got `node_modules/mod1`, `node_modules/mod2` inside both are a .gitignore that ignores the deeper `node_modules` inside those (as in `node_modules/mod1/node_modules`.  I add and remove modules often so I can't very well know and manually add rules to ignore `node_modules/mod1/.gitignore` or manually add `!node_modules/mod1/node_modules` all the time.  Basically I'm trying to deploy a meteor app and all the embedded `.gitignores` are making it impossible to get it all in git.

Answer (score 14):

The key to the problem here is that a parent directory is excluded. From `$ man gitignore`:

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

Here's how I've gotten it to work. Given:

```
/a/...
/b/foo
/c/...
```

`/.gitignore`:

```
/*
!/b
```

Then `/b/foo` will show up as included files while everything in `/a` and `/c` will be excluded.  The trade off is that you have to do add a negation for all of the parents of any directory in which you want to include files.

Comment: Why not use `!/b/**/*`?

Comment: Can't respond without more explanation from you.

Answer (score 9):

As far as i know there's no way to do it. As the local .gitignore will overwrite the root ginignore
My workaround is adding manually.

```
git add --force [ your file and folder]
```

Comment: child `.gitignore` didn't work for me as the parent overrides any child folder settings. If you force add using `git add -f myfile.txt` it will start tracking changes bypassing the parent `.gitignore` settings.